# Interface usage within three projects

Tags: vb.net

I will try to simplify as possible. In my solution i got 3 separated projects:

```
Main - where i use Bal
Bal - business logic, eg. classes:
      Artikel
      Material
Dal - data layer logic, eg. classes:
      DALArtikel
      DALMaterial
```

Now Dal's classes implements interface IDAL which looks like follows:

```
Public Interface IDAL
    Function isExist(name As String) As Boolean
    Function GetIdByName(name As String) As Integer
    Function GetNameById(pId As Integer) As String
End Interface
```

Then i can call interface's methods from Bal's project. Every BAL's class has it's DAL class like for Artikel is DALArtikel.

Now every BAL's classes inherits from one Base class which looks like below. This Base class implements interface similar to mentioned above called IGetInformation

```
Public Class Base
    Implements IGetInformation

    Property Id As Integer
    Property DAL As DataLayer.IDAL

Protected Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(dal As DataLayer.IDAL)
        Me.DAL = dal
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(pId As Integer)
        _Id = pId
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Function IsExist(name As String) As Boolean Implements IGetInformation.IsExist
        Return DAL.isExist(name)
    End Function

    Public Overridable Function GetNameById(pId As Integer) As String Implements IGetInformation.GetNameById
        Return DAL.GetNameById(pId)
    End Function

    Public Overridable Function GetIdByName(pName As String) As Integer Implements IGetInformation.GetIdByName
        Return DAL.GetIdByName(pName)
    End Function
```

Mentioned interface:

```
Public Interface IGetInformation
      Function isExist(name As String) As Boolean
      Function GetIdByName(name As String) As Integer
      Function GetNameById(pId As Integer) As String
End Interface
```

So every Bal's class like Artikel is constructed as following:

```
Public Class Artikel
    Inherits Base

  Property Serie As String
    Property Nummer As String
    Property Name As String

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New DALArtikel)
    End Sub
    Sub New(pId As Integer)
        MyBase.New(New DALArtikel)
        Id = pId
    End Sub
    Sub New(pId As Integer, pSerie As String)
        MyBase.New(New DALArtikel)
        Id = pId
        Serie = pSerie
    End Sub
```

This way i can instatiate artikel class in Main project and call it's e.g isExist method without specyfing specific DAL class associated with it as in Artikel class constructor it was already specified. The problem is now when i want to add new method which will be not in IDAL interface i have to implement like this in Artikel:

```
Public Function IsExistBarcode(barcode As String) As Boolean
        Return New DataLayer.DALArtikel().CheckIfBarcodeExist(barcode)
End Function
```

so this time i have to specify DALArtikel before i call CheckIfBarcodeExist as my property DAL doesn't know it.

Generally i don't like the way as it is currently, you see that i use two separate exactly the same content interfaces for bal's and dal's projects and the logic behind. Do you know other efficient way which i could change current logic to be let's say 'better'?

Appreciate possible improvment example according to my situation. Sorry for long post but couldn't make it more less. If something unclear let me know.

Comment: If `IDAL` and `IGetInformation` are exactly the same, I am assuming that your only concern is the name? Then find a name that fits both scenario IMO.

Comment: probably the problem is this whole architecture i wrote which i feel is not good. Awaiting for some possible improvment out of it.

Comment: Gotcha. I personally don't find anything wrong with it, other than the duplicated interface. In any event, if there is not an issue with your code, then you may want to post this on CodeReview instead.

Comment: ok let's say how to fix this two interfaces problem, do i need them both? Keep in mind one of them is in DAL and one of them resisting in Bal. How to use only one for both if they are the same? Or this has to be like this?

Comment: Personally I have yet another project for all common/core functionality. I know that it would seem like an extra layer, or over complicated, but that's how I do it. I also usually have more than just one small interface (I have all of my logging code here, configuration, etc)

Comment: @HanletEscaño  so what you say is to create additional project and put interface there so both layers can use it?

Comment: Jimmy, yes. Only if it makes sense, and you absolutely need that other interface. That is my opinion anyway. But you may have better luck taking this to code review.